# Why can't I grant select privileges to all table in schema with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database, sql, schema

I have a database `my_database`, and it have some tables named `my_table_1`, `my_table_2`, ... , `my_table_128` under schema `public`. I need to grant select privileges for all tables in schema `public` to user `my_db_user`, so I execute SQL command below:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to my_db_user;
```

And it executed without error. But after I connect with user `my_db_user` and tried to select something, it displaied permission denied. And I tried execute SQL command below with admin user:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE public.my_table_1 TO my_db_user;
```

Then connect with user `my_db_user` and tried to select something, it works.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I'm facing exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

ERROR:  permission denied for table asm_info
SQL state: 42501

1. Connect with user who is superuser or user with grantable privileges.
2. **Connect to the database in which table exists**.  [Most Important]
3. Then, run the following command  :
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO developer;

-bash-4.1$ psql erp;    erp->database where table exists

erp=# \c

You are now connected to database "erp" as user "postgres".

erp=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO developer;

Answer (score 0):

Did you grant permissions to all tables before creating the tables?  If so, you may need to grant permissions again.

I like making all items in the public schema public to all users, so you may want to try:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public 
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;
```